# Adding BCC to Postfix header_checks within Zimbra does not work

Tags: postfix

I wonder if you please give me a hand here:

We're implementing a header_checks rule to our Zimbra MTA to BCC the emails from all users to its own archive mailbox automatically. The following is the rule:

```
/^From:(.*)<(.*)@domain.com>(.*)/ BCC $2@domain.com.archive
```

Once I send an email I get the following error message:

```
Oct  5 22:33:33 mta1 postfix/cleanup[21994]: warning: unknown command in header_checks map: BCC first.last@domain.com.archive
```

I ran manually a postmap -q to check the rule and it goes fine:

```
[zimbra@mta1 ~]$ postmap -q 'From: FistName LastName <firstname.lastname@domain.com>' pcre:/opt/zimbra/conf/custom_header_checks
BCC first.last@domain.com.archive
```

I tried several ways but no luck... This is just postfix regex, nothing related to Zimbra itself, I guess...

Zimbra 8.6 with mail_version 2.11.1

Answer (score 2):

My man pages, let me show you them:

> BCC user@domain
>
> Add the specified address as a BCC recipient, and inspect the next input line. The address must have a local part and domain part. The number of BCC addresses that can be added is limited only by the amount of available storage space.
>
> Note 1: the BCC address is added as if it was specified with NOTIFY=NONE. The sender will not be notified when the BCC address is undeliverable, as long as all down-stream software implements RFC 3461.
>
> Note 2: this ignores duplicate addresses (with the same delivery status notification options).
>
> **This feature is available in Postfix 3.0 and later.**

(Emphasis added)

Comment: Womble, thanks very much for your answer... I missed that version line. I'll try it with a newer postfix version.